# During resize, set a miniumum and maximum resize control

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, fullcalendar-scheduler, fullcalendar-5

I have an appointment set for today between 2pm and 3pm, so 1 hours, for exemple.

I want to be able to control this appointment during the resize. Let's say this appointment can't be resized less than 30 minutes or more than 2 hours.

How can I control that minium and maximum ?

I want the person managing the scheduler to be unauthorized to move once these times are passed.

Comment: You can use https://fullcalendar.io/docs/eventResize to get the necessary info once the resizing has taken place, and then write code to check the duration is within the limits you want. Then you can call the provided "revert" function if you want to disallow the change.

Comment: Hi. Thanks ADyson for your comment. That's what i did. But i want to go beyond that. I want the person trying to resize the event, to be able to move freely, until it reach the minimum/maximum time.

Comment: ok, that wasn't clear in your question. It's always better to share your code and give a description of what you've already achieved, so we know exactly what the scenario is.

Comment: As far as I can see, there is no callback in fullCalendar which would be triggered _during_ resizing - only at the beginning and end. Your existing solution is "good enough" (assuming it's accompanied by server-side validation of the duration when the event is saved, of course) and that's probably what you'll have to live with.

Comment: Of course though, you can prevent resizing less than 30 minutes by making 30 minutes the minimum slotDuration in the settings. Maximum is more of a problem.